# How can I fetch the details of the other participant of an array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

I want to get the details of the other participant of the chat (only two partcipants), but I could only fetch the details of the person that fetch the data .

below is my code

```js
//Get ChatList
export const getChats = async(req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.id

    try {
        const chats = await ChatModel.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    participantId : userId
                }
            },
            { $addFields: {"userObjectid": {"$toObjectId": userId}}},
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from : "users",
                    localField: "userObjectid",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as : "userDetails"
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    "_id": 1,
                    "participantId": 1,
                    "lastMessage": 1,
                    "unread": 1,
                    "updatedAt": 1,
                    "userDetails._id" : 1,
                    "userDetails.username" : 1,
                    "userDetails.firstname" : 1,
                    "userDetails.lastname" : 1,
                    "userDetails.profilePicture": 1
                }
            }
        ])
        
        res.status(200).json(chats.sort((a,b) =>{
            return a.updatedAt - b.updatedAt;
        }))
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I used aggregation switch case to achieve the solution.

```js
//Get ChatList
export const getChats = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;

  try {
    const chats = await ChatModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          participantId: userId,
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          sender: { $indexOfArray: ["$participantId", userId] }
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          recipient: {
            $switch: {
              branches: [
                { case: { $eq: ["$sender", 0] }, then: 1 },
                { case: { $eq: ["$sender", 1] }, then: 0 },
              ],
              default: 0,
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          userObjectid: {
            $toObjectId: { $arrayElemAt: ["$participantId", "$recipient"] },
          },
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "userObjectid",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "userDetails",
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          participantId: 1,
          lastMessage: 1,
          unread: 1,
          updatedAt: 1,
          "userDetails._id": 1,
          "userDetails.username": 1,
          "userDetails.firstname": 1,
          "userDetails.lastname": 1,
          "userDetails.profilePicture": 1,
        },
      },
    ]);

    res.status(200).json(
      chats.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.updatedAt - b.updatedAt;
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```